# command line with cassandra

Tags: cassandra, command-line-arguments, apache-pig

how can i pass the value as command line arguments in Cassandra PIG Script.

Below line for syntax for execute the PIG Script

{apache-cassandra-0.4.0-src path}/contrib/pig/bin/pig_cassandra –param argument = Value script.pig

then i got the below error
[main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/ec2-user/apache-cassandra-0.7.4-src/contrib/pig/pig_1302092850679.log
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Encountered unexpected arguments on command line - please check the command line.
Details at logfile: /home/ec2-user/apache-cassandra-0.7.4-src/contrib/pig/pig_1302092850679.log

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post any relevant details from the log file mentioned in your question?

Answer (score 0):

The source for pig_cassandra shows

```
export PIG_OPTS=$PIG_OPTS" -Dudf.import.list=org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig"
cat "$cwd/../build/bootstrap.pig" - | $PIG_HOME/bin/pig $*
```

Checking out pig ...

http://wiki.apache.org/pig/ParameterSubstitution

Did you try

`-param argument=Value script.pig`